# How does geofences behave when there are overlapping CLRegions

Tags: ios, core-location, geofencing, clregion

I can't seem to find any information on how Core Location handles overlapping geofences. In my particular case I was wondering if a smaller geofence would be registered over a bigger, overlapping region. Does someone know this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Core Location will register when you enter a geofenced area whether you are currently in another area or not.  Consider this example for a clear understanding.

If I set a geofence around the entire United States and a smaller geofence around the state of Florida.

When I Enter the United States it will register that I entered the United States geofence.  When I enter Florida, it will register that I entered the Florida geofence, but I don't leave the United States geofence; I am now in both geofences.  If I go to Georgia, it will register that I exited the Florida geofence, but I am still in the United States Geofence.  If I exit Florida through the ocean and leave Florida and the United States, it will register that I have exited both the United States and Florida geofences.

So, no.  Smaller geofences are not registered over a bigger overlapping region.  They are both registered as if they know nothing about the other geofences that are being monitored.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Is there any property for currently active regions, or do I have to handle an array with i/o from -didEnter: and -didExit myself?

Comment: I've always handled with an array from didEnter and didExit